# Ajax JQuery reculsive modal dialog mvc3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, modal-dialog

I am editing some content in popup as bellow:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Show() {
        return PartialView("ShowControl");
    }

}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/favicon.png")" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Show", "Show", new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "modal-dialog-container",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
})
<div id="modal-dialog-container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ShowControl.cshtml

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js")" type="text/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        height: 200,
        width: 250,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
    });
});
</script>
<div id="dialog" title="Ttile">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Show", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { 
 UpdateTargetId = "modal-dialog-container",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
})) {
        <p>
            Content</p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            @Html.ActionLink("Go Home", "Index")
        </p>
 }
</div>
```

The problem is that pressing submit will recreate new modal dialog and will not destroy the old one.
How to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just noting: I'd directly launch the modal dialog from within a piece of JavaScript code in your Index.cshtml view rather than using partials and then somehow letting the "server" launch the dialog. This will result in a better UI experience and probably will also be less complex than your approach.

Comment: This is a pice of bigger solution. This popup responsible for editing an object. When object is not valid it comes back with validation error.